# How to shard any new collections automatically?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I shard a new collection like this now :

```
sh.enableSharding(<database>)
db.createCollection("<collection>")
sh.shardCollection("<database>.<collection>",{"_id":1})
```

I wonder if there is a way to shard any new collections in the database without any more operations, maybe like this:

```
sh.enableSharding(<database>)
sh.shardAllCollections("<database>",{"_id":1}) // It is fake
db.createCollection("<collection1>") //shard automatically
db.createCollection("<collection2>") //shard automatically
db.createCollection("<collection3>") //shard automatically
```

Comment: This really isn't a programming question but it's really not suitable for migration to [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) in it's present form anyway. You really should expand on what your intention is and what you really have to do and ask that question there instead. I do really suggest that you "fully" read about sharding and understand what it is and "isn't" for that matter. I think a little more understanding actually would address for you why such a thing does not exist nor would be practical. From the Manual: [Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/)

Comment: Even from a programming perspective, I fear this question does not make sense. If you create collections dynamically, do so explicitly and shard them.